# My bot replies is being marked as "show additional replies..."

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I’m building a bot which posts message from students as a campaign on twitter. I wrote the bot using Node.js

My problem is that the bot replies with a phrase (it’s not a link or a media, just text without explicit words) but Twitter is marking these messages as “Show additional replies, including those that may contain offensive content”.

I marked the button on privacy setting for “Display media that may contain sensitive content” but it doesn't seem to change it. Anybody knows what’s wrong?? I appreciate your help.

Here is a screenshot of how the replies are showing  for reference:

- [Image with sensitive content block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9BED.jpg)

Here is some of the code I'm using to post the tweets:

```
Bot.get('search/tweets', { q: '@orgullopucp -filter:retweets', since_id: last_mention_id }, function(err, data, response) {
        if (err){
          console.log('Error!', err);
          return false;
        }
        /* Next, let's search for Tweets that mention our bot, starting after the last mention we responded to. */
        if (data.statuses.length) {
          console.log(data.statuses);
          data.statuses.forEach(function(status) {
            console.log(status.id_str);
            console.log(status.text);
            console.log(status.user.screen_name);

            /* Now we can respond to each tweet. */
            Bot.post('statuses/update', {
              possibly_sensitive:false,
              status: '@' + status.user.screen_name + ' ' + random_from_array(sentences),
              in_reply_to_status_id: status.id_str
            }, function(err, data, response) {
              if (err){
                  /* TODO: Proper error handling? */
                console.log('Error!', err);
              }
              else{
                fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/last_mention_id.txt', status.id_str, function (err) {
                  /* TODO: Error handling? */
                  if(err){
                    console.log('Error!', err);
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          /* No new mentions since the last time we checked. */
          console.log('No new mentions...');      
        }
      });    
    });
    response.sendStatus(200);
```

Comment: Were you able to find answers to this?
I am currently experiencing same.
Thanks